# If i wil change background colour of input type check box is checked use CSS only? it is possible or not?

Tags: html, css

**change background colour type one line css only**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="HP">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this could work, some sort of JavaScript would be needed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do it is to assign a unicode content in it and hide the original one by doing something like below.

```css
input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  }
  
  
  input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "\2714";  
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


input[type=checkbox]:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  color: white;
}


input:autofill {
  background: red;
}

input, input:-moz-autofill, input:-moz-autofill-preview {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="HP">
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Mac Firefox though.

Comment: @RickardElimää I think you have to change your setting on Firefox itself for it to work the autofill of the Firefox are different from the other browser. This is the first things that comes to my head. I will investigate that more, theres only about between 9-10% uses safari between 7-8% users of firefox.